# Search by two different fields using 1 value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In database I've got 2 different tokens used for different integrations. I would like to recognize user if integration code is specified. Integration tokens are unique, however each user record needs exactly 2 tokens.

Easiest way to do it would be to pass additional param, however I have to integrate with some legacy app that I can't modify.

So far I've written something like this, however I believe there is more clean and more "railsy" way to obtain same result.
Could you help me?

```
def user
  target_user = nil

  target_user = User.where.not(user_token_type1: nil)
      .find_by(user_token_type1: params[:user_token])

  target_user = User.where.not(user_token_type2: nil)
      .find_by(user_token_type2: params[:user_token]) if target_user.blank?

  target_user || user_not_found
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if val = params[:user_token].presence
  query = "user_token_type1 = :token OR user_token_type2 = :token"
  User.where(query, {token: val}).last
end || user_not_found
```

I read your comment and if you must, you can do it the following way too:

```
val = params[:token_val]

User.where.not(user_token_type1: nil).find_by(user_token_type1: val) || \
User.where.not(user_token_type2: nil).find_by(user_token_type2: val)
```

But that can obviously result in two queries where one would have done the job perfectly.

Comment: Thank you, but providing empty user_token in params will result in finding user with no field filled. Instead of param validation I would prefer to perform AR validation using `.where.not(user_token_type1: nil)` because there are more params to come. it would lead in `user_token_type1 = :token AND user_token_type1 != :nil_token` and passing `nil_token: nil` to the params hash. I think here is more clean way of doing that ;)

Comment: No, providing an empty user token would fail the `if` condition and the code will work as desired. I've added a `presence` method to ensure that `""` fails the condition as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this:

```
User.where("user_token_type1 = ? OR user_token_type2 = ?", params[:user_token], params[:user_token])
```

Also, remove `User.where.not(user_token_type1: nil)`. Add a constraint to your model so that you can trust your data instead of adding that boilerplate.